# Firebase Timestamp difference between current Timestamp and database timestamp error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have written a `TimeValidityCheckUtil` which determines if the snapshot from a particular listener is within a given time-frame of the current time of the device. This has this method, `checkIfTImeValid`

```
  public static boolean checkIfTimeValid(Timestamp dbTimestamp)
    {    
        Timestamp currentTimestamp = Timestamp.now();    
        Long seconds = currentTimestamp.getSeconds() - dbTimestamp.getSeconds();  
        if(seconds> 10)
        {
            return false;
        }    
        return true;    
    }
```

The database structure is in Firestore and is as follows:

```
"ABC"-|
      |
      |-"documentId"-|
                     |
                     |-"some_key" - "string"
                     |-"timestamp" - timestamp
```

This is what happens, device A creates a documentId and the object with the timestamp.

Device B listens to this documentId  and invokes the `checkIfTimeValid` to check if the the operation by document A was within 10s of the current Timestamp (to check if it's recent)

Even if this process is happening instantly, the device shows the difference between the timestamps as ~57-62s which according to me should not be more than 1-5s.

Why this is happening?

Comment: From where are you calling this method? Please add more context. Please add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: Hey @AlexMamo, I have made the suggested changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Timestamp.now()` is calculated using the local device's time. If the device clock is out of sync with Firebase, that difference will be reflected here.

I am not aware of the Firestore equivalent, but in the RTDB, you can use special location `/.info/serverTimeOffset` to estimate the difference between clocks in milliseconds.

```
firebase.database().ref('/.info/serverTimeOffset').once('value')
  .then((snap) => {
    var offset = snap.val();
    console.log('Server time delta in ms: ', offset);
    // var estimatedServerTimeMs = new Date().getTime() + offset;
  })
  .catch(console.error)
```

[RTDB Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#clock-skew)

Comment: You can also "ping" time.google.com, the timeserver used by GCP/Functions using this [SNTP Client](https://github.com/aslamanver/sntp-client-android) to manually estimate the client device time offset.

Comment: Thanks @samthecodingman.  Is there a way I always fetch the Timestamp from the server instead of the local device's time so that I do not have to thrive on offset estimates?

Comment: That's what the SNTP client is for. It will return the server timestamp

Comment: There is no equivalent for Firestore.