# How can I get Timestamp from Firestore server without bothering for the case when device clock is out of sync with Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is in reference to this question [Firebase Timestamp difference between current Timestamp and database timestamp error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59907955/firebase-timestamp-difference-between-current-timestamp-and-database-timestamp-e)

If I use `Timestamp.now()` there are cases where the device clock is out of sync with Firestore and my time calculations are not accurate. I want to get the exact time from the Firestore server without being bothered by out of sync cases. Is there any way I could do that?

I have seen `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` but there I cannot find a way to calculate anything using it, since it's return type is `FieldValue` and I am unable to parse it to `Timestamp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious but economically adverse way is to write to Firestore Database, the timestamp and read it again from there.

```
db.collection("TimestampChecker").document("some_string").set(new TimestampGetter()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

            db.collection("TimestampChecker").document("some_string").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                    if(task.getResult()!=null)
                    {
                        TimestampGetter timestampGetter = task.getResult().toObject(TimestampGetter.class);
                        Date dateNow = timestampGetter.getTimestampNow();

                    }

                }
            });

        }
    });
```

And TimestampGetter can be a class like this:

```
public class TimestampGetter {
@ServerTimestamp
private Date timestampNow;

public TimestampGetter(Date timestampNow) {
    this.timestampNow = timestampNow;
}

public TimestampGetter() {
}

public Date getTimestampNow() {
    return timestampNow;
}

public void setTimestampNow(Date timestampNow) {
    this.timestampNow = timestampNow;
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` it means you let Firestore generate a timestamp for you. Please note that this timestamp is generated **entirely** on the server. It is not generated as document ids are, for instance on the client.

> I cannot find a way to calculate anything using it since it's return type is FieldValue and I am unable to parse it to Timestamp.

When calling FieldValue's [serverTimestamp()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldValue.html#serverTimestamp()) method, it true that type of the object that is returned is `FieldValue` but this only used to be passed as an argument when you need that timestamp property. Please check how you can add a timestamp to a Cloud Firestore document:

- [ServerTimestamp is always null on Firebase Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474957/servertimestamp-is-always-null-on-firebase-firestore/48475027#48475027)

So if you query the database and you get a document that has a property that was set using `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`, the type of object that is returned is [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html). Since you get a `Date` object back, you can do whatever you want with it.

However, in Firebase Realtime Database we have another mechanism. So please see this answer:

- [How to save the current date/time when I add new value to Firebase Realtime Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43584244/how-to-save-the-current-date-time-when-i-add-new-value-to-firebase-realtime-data)

So, in this case, it's totally different since we are using the time since the Unix epoch, in milliseconds and not a `Date` object.

**Edit:**

It sounds like your question started off about how to get a Timestamp from Firestore, but is actually just about how to structure a document so two devices can read the same document. However, to make it work, you should use two properties of type `Date`. One for device A and one for device B. Check the schema below:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- yourCollection (collection)
        |
        --- yourDocument (document)
              |
              --- deviceA: January 24, 2020 at 3:37:59 PM UTC+3 
              |
              --- deviceB: January 25, 2020 at 3:37:59 PM UTC+3 //Timestamp
```

To get the values of `deviceA` and `deviceB` properties, please use my answer from the following post:

- [How to get server Timestamp from Firestore in an android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59908720/how-to-get-server-timestamp-from-firestore-in-an-android-device/59908767#59908767)

Now you can compare both timestamps.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Mamo, I also wanted the current server Timestamp in device B in a Date Object , so that I can compare it with the Timestamp stored in the database by device A. How can I achieve that?

Comment: In that case, you should store a timestamp property in each document you need. For example, if device A reads a document with a particular timestamp and device B reads another document with another timestamp, then you can simply compare them. So both documents should store that property.

Comment: Device B reads the document stored by device A. There are no separate documents. But to understand whether the document read by device B is recent, I need to compare the timestamp from the document (that was set by Device A) and the timestamp generated by Device B when it read the document. 
In that case, I would need the server timestamp in device B. How can I achieve that?

Comment: I think my comment was misunderstood. 2 devices are NOT reading the same document. As mentioned in my comment, device A is storing it and device B is reading it. I just need the server timestamp in device B, not from the document stored, but the Server Timestamp when Device B particularly read it.

Comment: I think the [edited answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59908767/5246885) will help you understand better, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206636/discussion-between-maverick7-and-alex-mamo).